# FMX - TAction OnUpdate doesn't work

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, taction, tactionlist

I have an FMX form that contains a button and a TActionList with a TAction 'Action1'.
Action1 has an Execute procedure and an Update procedure, and the property 'Action' of the button is set to Action1.

If I run the application on windows, it enters in the OnUpdate event and do all the stuff it should;
If I run it on an Android device, it doesn't enter in the OnUpdate event.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

**Edit:**
I'm using Delphi 10.2

Comment: As I said, it has an execute procedure and is assigned to a button, if it wasn't I know it wouldn't work. The strange thing is that it's working on windows and not on android

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully.

Comment: How do we reproduce this issue?

Comment: See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18837

Comment: To reproduce, create a new fmx application with a form. Put on the form a TActionList and a Button. Assign a new action to that button. Assign OnExecute and OnUpdate events to the action and do some stuff into them. Lunch the application on an android device

Comment: Assuming you have Delphi 10.2 or 10.2.1, you can fix it by updating to 10.2.2. Preferably, you should update to 10.2.3. In future, please state which version of Delphi you're using

Comment: Yes, I have 10.2.. Then i'll try to update and I'll let you know if it works, thanks

Comment: @DaveNottage is it possible to fix it replacing some units?

Comment: It's possible to fix it (I had to in those versions), but it's far easier and more reliable to update to 10.2.3, since a number of other problems have also been fixed

Comment: How can i Fix it without updating? I'd prefer to fix this just for now